# MSExcel using MCONCAT to return unique values in one cell

Tags: excel

I'm using MCONCAT (part of the morefunc Excel add-in package) to pull extract unique matches from a list of data, my code is as follows:

```
=MCONCAT(UNIQUEVALUES(OFFSET(B$1,MATCH(D2,A$2:A$68761,0),,COUNTIF(A$2:A$68761,D2))),", ")
```

This all works OK providing that there is more than one result, otherwise it doesn't seem to work.  It DOES work without using UNIQUEVALUES but that returns an enormous amount of results for some lines.

```
=MCONCAT(OFFSET(B$1,MATCH(D8,A$2:A$68761,0),,COUNTIF(A$2:A$68761,D8)),", ")
```

Does anyone know how to make my first query work for rows with only a single match?

Many Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "....providing that there is more than one result", do you mean when the offset range is a single cell or when UNIQUEVALUES has only one value? What happens then, do you get an error?

Comment: Hi Barry. Yes, if the offset range is a single cell then it returns a VALUE error, as a workaround I just used the code from above and then did a normal VLOOKUP on anything that got the error code but this is a process I'm going to need to repeat a lot so a more efficient resolution would be ideal.

Comment: It may be that I'm using the wrong function: I basically need to search a spreadsheet based on the contents of a cell and return every result in one cell divided by commas.  The list of of search terms is 10,000 rows and the master list containing the results is over 60,000 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that UNIQUEVALUES function needs to be passed an "array" and in most cases OFFSET does that.....except when the COUNTIF = 1 and the OFFSET is then just a single value (not an array containing one value) and UNIQUEVALUES doesn't like that so returns an error. I don't know a particularly elegant way round that, perhaps just build a VLOOKUP into the formula when there's an error, i.e.

`=IFERROR(MCONCAT(UNIQUEVALUES(OFFSET(B$1,MATCH(D2,A$2:A$68761,0),,COUNTIF(A$2:A$68761,D2))),", "),VLOOKUP(D2,A$2:B$68761,2,0))`